# 'If not' to avoid zero division

Tags: python, divide-by-zero

My code below returns a `zerodivision` error when `occupied_spaces` is empty.

```
occupied_spaces = [ ]

cars = occupied_spaces.count(1)
spaces = occupied_spaces.count(0)

if not occupied_spaces:
    print('The list is empty')
    
percentage = cars/len(occupied_spaces) * 100

print(percentage, '%')
```

Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: I assume len is to get size of array, so if occupied_spaces is empty size is 0. Looks like it python so if array is empty it will just print message that list is empty and then go to pecentage calcualtion

Comment: What do you mean why this happens? If `occupied_spaces` is empty then its `len` is `0`. So you can't do `cars/len(occupied_spaces)`... Probably you want to put the last 2 lines under a `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but let me guess. Looks like you want to check if occupied spaces is empty then print message otherwise calculate percentage. So code should be smth like that. If array is empty function len will return you 0

```
occupied_spaces = [ ]

if not occupied_spaces:
    print('The list is empty')
else:
    percentage = occupied_spaces.count(1) / len(occupied_spaces) * 100
    print(percentage, '%')
```

Looks like its python so you need to align code properly